# Why is my worn item detector not working? (1.15.2 Minecraft)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have worked on creating an item that can make you fly by sneaking but the detector is consistently failing. It is a scoreboard system and this is the item NBT:

```
leather_boots{display:{Name:"[{\"text\":\"Glass Boots\",\"italic\":false,\"color\":\"white\"}]",Lore:["[{\"text\":\"Can be used to fly!\",\"italic\":true,\"color\":\"dark_blue\"}]"],color:3847130},Enchantments:[{id:flame,lvl:1}],Unbreakable:1,HideFlags:39,AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.armor",Amount:66,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:171565600,UUIDMost:99,Slot:feet,Name:"generic.armor"}]} 1.
```

Scoreboard command:

```
/scoreboard players add @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:100b,display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Glass Boots\",\"italic\":false,\"color\":\"white\"}"}}]}] Wearing_Glass 1
```

What is wrong with my command?

Answer (score 1):

You are using an array in the 1st `Name` tag, and not on the 2nd. This means the following are different:

```
[{"text":"hello world"}]
 {"text":"hello world"}
```

When performing comparisons on NBT JSON tags, it does a text comparison against the raw JSON elements. This means, that even if the text will render the same, it must be typed exactly the same or it won’t register.

To make things simpler, surround the entire JSON text string in single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"`. **(1.15 only)** Try the bottom instead of the top:

```
Name:"{\"text\":\"hello world\"}"
Name:'{"text":"hello world"}'
```

Please let me know in the comments if any additional errors arise.

Comment: I have done your suggestion and maybe I did something wrong but it is still not detecting my boots. scoreboard players add @a[nbt={Inventory:{Slot:100b,display:{Name:'{"text":"Glass Boots","italic":false,"color":"white"}'}}}] Wearing_Glass 1. I believe I got something wrong in the nbt because I fiddled around with it for a while. If you could post the scoreboard fixed the would be helpful. I am newer to commands in Minecraft so this is much appreciated.

Comment: To make things easier, please [edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/371613/edit) your question to include the new commands, instead of posting them in a comment. Thanks!